# form with input attributes 'required' and 'pattern' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

Hi i have this code with HTML5:

```html
<form id="pay" method="GET" class="row g-3" style="display:none;" type="hidden">
  <strong>Date</strong></a><br>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="name_users_card" class="form-label">user card</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_users_card"
           pattern="^[A-Za-zèòà\s]$"
           minlength="3"
           maxlength="20"
           placeholder="titolare carta"
           title="take a valid name" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I try to run the code, the required control is not working. Why?

Comment: `style="display:none;" type="hidden"` is going to be a problem for your `<form>`. `</a>` without an opening tag is an issue. `^[A-Za-zèòà\s]$` as your pattern means only match a String that starts and ends with a single character that is within your character set. Use `^[A-Za-zèòà\s]+$` or `^[A-Za-zèòà\s]{3,20}$` instead. By the way that will match three spaces, and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't actually understand the problem but you have an incomplete `<a>` tag and you made your form hidden by setting `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

Your **Regular Expression Pattern**:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]$
```

is a *single character*.

If you want *zero to any number of characters*, use:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]*$
```

If you want *one to any number of characters*, use:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]+$
```

If you want *exactly twenty characters*, use:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]{20}$
```

If you want *three to twenty characters*, use:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]{3,20}$
```

If you want *three to any number of characters*, use:

```
^[A-Za-zèòà\s]{3,}$
```